# Converting a regex with negative lookahead from a PHP format to a Javascript format

Tags: php, javascript, regex, cross-browser

My need is to strip embedded line breaks but not paragraph breaks when the browser is not IE.

The reason for this need is to nicely format alert messages. Turns out that the major non-IE browsers format the messages nicely by themselves, inserting line breaks in a nice place. However, IE will not do this. So a non-formatted line simply expands the width of the alert box. My solution is to format all alert messages with line breaks for IE, and strip out the line breaks when the browser is not IE. This gives a nicely formatted alert message regardless of the browser. If this extra processing is not done, then you either have ugly wide alert boxes in IE (without any breaks) or ragged formated text in the non-IE browsers as the hard-coded line breaks and browser-added line breaks are both present.

A further complication is that I don't want to strip ALL line breaks, because doing so would also remove paragraph breaks. So the final requirement is to strip all single line breaks but not "paragraph" breaks, which are simply two consecutive line breaks.

Yet a further complication is that the strings are being processed in PHP, which requires backslashes to be escaped. So rather than considering line breaks as \n, they are \\n, and the regex has to look for the \\n pattern.

Also please note: the majority of our important "popup messages and dialogs" are done using jquery to provide a nicely formatted display. So another approach would be to do away with alerts entirely and replace them with jquery dialogs. However, in these cases we do not desire to go that far, and simply want a nicely formatted alert box.

We normally do the regex processing in PHP, which works fine. The problem is that I would also like to have the equivalent processing available in pure javascript if this is possible. I am suspecting that the negative lookahead processing might not be supported in javascript, at least in the way it is in PHP. If so, that raises the difficulty. So far I have been unable to come up with a javascript version.

Here is the PHP code that achieves the intended result:

```
/**
 * Removes embedded line breaks but not paragraph breaks if not IE
 *
 * @param string $message - formatted for IE, with embedded paragraph and line breaks
 * $is_IE - set elsewhere to indicate if the browser is IE
 */
function FormatAlert($message)
{
    global $is_IE;
    return ($is_IE) ?  $message : preg_replace('/(?<!\\\n)\\\n(?!\\\n)/', ' ', $message);
}
```

Thus the need is to create an equivalent regex for javascript.

In further thinking, it occurs to me that if I can come up with a single regex then the workaround would be to temporarily replace double line breaks used for paragraph breaks with a special symbol, then replace the remaining single line breaks, and then finally replace the special symbol with the double line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript supports negative lookahead, but not lookbehind.

Originally I answered you might not need lookbehind with: `str.replace(/\n(?!\n)/g, '');` which will remove all newlines not followed by another. This might work fine for your case of an alert popup, but *it will actually remove the last newline in a double-newline sequence* (since it is not followed by a newline) turning a double-lined paragraph break into a simple newline. To fix this you will need to use another replace to put back the other newlines by replacing any left with an extra that was stripped: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/99jCd/

```
var str = "This is an oddly\nbroken paragraph that\nwill turn"+
          "into one line.\n\nThis will still be a new\nand separate"+
          "paragraph that\nis also not broken.";    
str = str.replace(/\n(?!\n)/g, ' ').replace(/\n+\s/g, '\n\n');​
```

Comment: Also, the php version is complicated by the need for the three backslashes. It won't work without them. I think this is because backslashes have to be escaped, and thus in the string that gets processed by the php before being sent to javascript has to be written this way. Seems hard to understand to me, but it works. In any case, in the PHP there are two backslashes, so that the "raw" strong looks like this:  stuff\\nmore stuff.

Comment: In fact when I put your suggested code into my test harness, it breaks the javascript unless I escape each of the backslashes. That is, I have to make it as follows: var str = "This single line break will be removed:\\n, but this paragraph break (multiple line breaks) will not.\\n\\nThis is still a new paragraph!"; Need to take a break now, so will test further a bit later.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there are strings handled in PHP in various double-quoted string formats. So the backslashes have to be escaped. The strings are processed at that level too, so the issue becomes replacing \\n but not replacing \\n\\n. I hope this clarifies the problem statement.

Comment: @JeffreySimon Yes, if you need to double escape a string in PHP so it renders correctly then you'll need to handle that from the PHP code. Just make sure what is rendered to the page has "\n" as a newline character, as this is both where the string is rendered **and** where the javascript will be executed. I've updated my answer to provide a way to preserve newlines (for the lack of negative lookbehind).

Comment: In playing around with your suggestion, and with escaping the backslashes, the single line break is replaced. However the double line break is replaced with a single line break. So it does not yet meet the requirements.

Comment: @JeffreySimon Yup, I just changed my answer to accomodate that. You can make a series of replaces to compensate for the lack of lookbehind support. See my updated answer and the accompanying jsfiddle. :)

Comment: I have simplified my test harness to use pure javascript rather than writing the javascript from php from within a double quoted string. This eliminates the extra layer of confusion by having to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Here is why your original suggestion is not working, and why the lookbehind is needed: when the regex sees the first single line break, it replaces it. When it sees the first of the double line breaks, it looksahead and sees the second one, and does not replace it. But then it sees the second of the line break pair, looks ahead and sees no further line breaks, so it replaces it. The lookbehind is needed to prevent this. I have not yet looked at your latest comment, but this comment should be informative.

Comment: Yes, it appears we are on the same page, and in fact the multiple replacing should do the trick. If so, I will mark this as the correct answer.